# How do I show contact list result into render view container

Tags: react-native

Using react-native-contact plugin in the doc shows below code:

```
var Contacts = require('react-native-contacts')

Contacts.getAll((err, contacts) => {
  if(err === 'denied'){
    // x.x
  } else {
    console.log(contacts)
  }
})
```

but how do I show `contacts` result into my view Container?

```
return (
            <Container>contact results here</Container>
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the contact plugin simply returns an array of objects. (Haven't used it personally).

The docs also say the getAll is a fairly intensive function and to cache the results. So how about doing it in the constructor. Save contacts to state and use map to display each contact with DisplayContact pure component.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  Contacts.getAll((err, contacts) => {
  if(err === 'denied'){
      // x.x
    } else {
      this.setState({ contacts });
      console.log('contacts set!', contacts);
    }
  })
}

render() {
  const { contacts } = this.state;
  return (
    <Container>
      {contacts.map((contact) => <DisplayContact contact={contact} /> )}
    </Container>
  );
}
```

DisplayContact:

```
const DisplayContact = (props) => {
  const { contact } = props;
  return (
    <View>
      <Text> {contact.recordID} </Text>
      <Text> {contact.familyName} </Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many places you can put those `.getAll` to (directly in render,  put it in your custom method, helper or service funcs). To make it faster you can can get contacts right in your `render()` method:

```
render() {
  let contactList = [];
  Contacts.getAll((err, contacts) => {
    if(err === 'denied'){
      // x.x
    } else {
     contactList = contacts;
    }
  )

  // Since contact list is an array of objects
  // https://github.com/rt2zz/react-native-contacts#example-contact-record
  // You can loop throw throw array and render them (I think better to create separate component <Contact>
  return (
    <div>
      {contactList.map((contact, index) =>{
        <span>{contact.givenName}</span>
        <span>{contact.familyName}</span>
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

If it does not work, you may want to wrap `Contacts.getAll` with Promise and render contact when promise resolved.